# Syntax error on token void, @ expected, among other issues on my first line on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, void

Well I am not totally sure what is going on with this one. On this simple code that will eventually update the host file automatically, I can not even get the damn thing to run without getting an error. On the line that starts "public void blocker1" i get these error messages in eclipse
Multiple markers at this line
        - Syntax error on token "void", @ 
         expected
        - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
         construct(s)
        - Syntax error on token ")", -> expected
Here is the code I have so far

```
package blocker1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;


public void blocker1(String url) {

    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    String hostsFile = "";
    if ((OS.indexOf("win") >= 0)) {
        hostsFile = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\newfile";
    } else if ((OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0)) {

        hostsFile = "etc/hosts";
    } else if ((OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0)) {
        hostsFile = "/etc/hosts";
    } else {

        System.err.println("Sorry, but your OS doesn't support blocking.");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    Files.write(Paths.get(hostsFile),
            ("127.0.0.1 " + url).getBytes(),
            StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

}

On my final closed bracket I also get the errorS Multiple markers at this line
        - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete 
         EnumDeclaration
        - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
         EnumHeader
        - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Modifier

Thanks to all who can help and if it is not completely obvious I am quite new at coding

Comment: Hey what's up!  So at first glance it doesn't appear as if you're programming inside of a class, which is definitely causing some of your issues.  In Java you have to write programs inside a class, so your best bet might just be to create new class file in your java project and paste your function in there, with all your imports at the top.  Hopefully this makes sense, I can post a link if you need an example.

Comment: Your method is not inside of a class declaration. You need to make it static.

Comment: Don't make it a static method - that is a bad practice in most cases. Create a class, put your method in the class, create an instance of the class (new MyClass() ) and call the method o the instance.

Comment: @ARC on my eclipse I did just create a new class, what you said is correct and fixed MOST of my issues, however now on my final bracket I get the error Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody.

Comment: @pczeus I believe ARC's solution may have fixed the problem, however could you explain how you would go about creating an instance and then calling the method?